# How to format numbers by (several different) locales in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, format, locale

Is there a correct way to format numbers by locale (getting the correct decimal separator) without modifying global state? This is for text generation server-side, so setlocale is not a good idea, and Babel does not yet support Python 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the *locale* module gets and sets global state.  This is intrinsic to the design of locale.

The various workarounds include setting locks or calling a subprocess as a service.

Comment: Right, I was afraid of that. Do you know of any existing minimal implementation for Python 3? (I'll roll my own for now unless there's a perfect match, but might package and release it if there is a need..)